# Bootstrap-Glyphicons on Ruby on rails net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I got the same problem like this thread:

[Rails 4.1 and Bootstrap 3 glyphicons are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914164/rails-4-1-and-bootstrap-3-glyphicons-are-not-working)

[Ruby on Rails Bootstrap Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255711/ruby-on-rails-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-working)

I solved it by following their answer but there's an issue when it loads.

I got this error on Console.

GET http:// localhost:3000/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

It loads so slow.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following in config/application.rb (within class Application < Rails::Application)
?

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
```

Check [this blog post.](http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/)

Comment: This could be related to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889338/javascript-not-loading-due-to-neterr-content-length-mismatch